# Usercontrol viewmodel wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a user control called AddUserControl which is used in MainWindow as a **edit** screen and there is **add** button in ribbon control, so the same AddUserControl should open. so i have created a AddWindow and plugged that usercontrol in AddWindow.

so should i make a viewmodel for AddUserControl cause same code is being repeated in both MainScreen and AddWindow? But usercontrol should not have its viewmodel. It will be really helpful if anyone will explain it?

Comment: If the UserControl is supposed to be independent of a specific view model, it has to expose dependency properties that can be bound to properties of any view model object in the current DataContext, like `<local:YourUserControl UcProperty="{Binding VmProperty}"/>`. If you put such a UserControl in a DataTemplate for a certain view model type (by setting the DataTemplate's `DataType` property), it will be created automatically when you assign an instance of the view model type to the `Content` property of a ContentControl.

Comment: The view model of the `MainWindow` may have a `User` property which returns an `AddUserViewModel` that the `AddUserControl` binds to. And you can set the `DataContext` of the `AddWindow` to another instance of `AddUserViewModel`. Then the `UserControl` will be reusable in both windows. The other option is to add dependency properties to the `UserControl` and bind these individually.

Comment: In my AddUserControl, i have some methods like upload files and perform some action like edit and save. There is like more than 10+ properties, so making dependency properties is a difficult task i guess. still can you please explain further or maybe different approach?

Comment: Can you post a visual like a UML or the code (View, any code behind, and ViewModel)?